# how to remove or customize the header of lightning-card in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, html, lightning-card

I want to add a dark blue colored header for lightning-card lwc, when i try to use a div tag at the top and color it blue there is a blank white space above it. Is there any way to remove this header or to customize it?[image: header element in inspect]

Answer (score 1):

lwc namespaced components are not easily customizable. You might want to look into using the blueprints to have fully customized components:

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/cards/

Comment: Or, alternatively, you can use the lightning-base-components package as a starting point.